# Discrete Morse theory and existence of minimal complex

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, discrete-morse-theory

A minimal complex is a CW complex whose only cells are the homology cells.

Is there some sort of criterion on CW complexes about existence of minimal complexes?

Actually I am working on a problem of understanding homotopy type of certain spaces 
(see: [How to show that a space has the homotopy type of wedge of spheres ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43711/how-to-show-that-a-space-has-the-homotopy-type-of-wedge-of-spheres))

My hope was to use discrete Morse theory (acyclic matching of face poset to be precise) and find the minimal complex. But then I don't know if the existence of the minimal complex is always guaranteed.

Comment: Have you read the Whitehead theorems on minimal CW-complexes?  They're in many textbooks, for example, G.W. Whitehead's text, or section 4.C of Hatcher's notes.  See the references in Hatcher's notes for more details. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not exactly what you asked, but it's certainly not the case that every CW complex has a discrete vector field where the Morse complex has trivial differential. In particular this would imply that  chain complex is simple-homotopy equivalent to a chain complex with no differential. However, simple-homotopy equivalence is well-known not to generate homotopy equivalence. In particular, the Whitehead torsion is an obstruction which lives in the Whitehead group of the fundamental group. Marshall Cohen's book on Whitehead torsion is the canonical place to learn about this.

Comment: Cohen's book is getting increasingly difficult to find. 

Comment: Yes, that's a shame. Do you know of a good reference for simple-homotopy theory that's easier to find?

Comment: Rourke and Sanderson's "Introduction to Piecewise-Linear Topology" is also out of print, and is near impossible to find. Milnor's "Whitehead Torsion" article is available on-line, is quite terse and contains much essential information.   I imagine between a books like Milnor's h-cobordism notes, Kosinski's book and Milnor's Whitehead torsion notes you could put together a reasonable course on the s-cobordism theorem. 

Comment: One can find a pdf-file with Cohen's book on the web as well as Rourke and Sanderson's "Introduction to Piecewise-Linear Topology".  

Comment: Milnor's paper on Whitehead torsion is also good. I don't know why that slipped my mind when I wrote this answer.

Comment: @JimConant That paper seems to have been written "too early". In particular, it contains the incorrect claim (Example 1.6) that the Whitehead group of $\mathbb{Z}\Pi$ for $\Pi$ a finite abelian group is trivial. The first counter-example is $\Pi = \mathbb{Z}/5$ whose whitehead group is $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: @ViditNanda: it was an early paper, but it is so well written that I still think it's worth reading. The incorrect claim you are talking about has a footnote explaining that the announced proof (by other authors) has serious problems. I am not aware of any mistakes within the paper itself.

Answer (score 1):

In [this](http://msp.org/pjm/2011/249-2/pjm-v249-n2-p06-s.pdf) recent paper, Kozlov gives a sufficient condition for an acyclic matching on a CW complex to be a wedge of spheres (it is, unfortunately, not necessary)

Comment: One of your "sufficients" should be a different word?

Comment: I think the second should be "necessary" instead, but cannot check as I don't have access at the moment.